# Rails 3 — Omniauth routing error, works on local but not on my server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, routes, omniauth

I'm trying to use Omniauth to allow users to login to my Rails app using Facebook. Locally, omniauth automatically redirects the browser to Facebook for authentication using the following link:

`<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook" %>`

It redirects back as is expected (no callback error) and I am then able to log out.

The issue occurs when I try to upload my application to my server. For some reason Omniauth isn't kicking in and it doesn't do the redirect. Instead it just points the browser to a non-existant directory in my app (http://sharedchecklist.com/auth/facebook) and spits out this error:

`Routing Error`

`No route matches "/auth/facebook"`

I've done a lot of searching over the past few hours to try and figure out what the issue could be. I've made sure to changee the the site and canvas URLs to my app's address. It isn't an issue with callback.

It's almost like omniauth isn't there…

Has anyone encountered this issue before? I'm fairly new to rails but I've been able to figure through any issues before which makes this one all the most frustrating.

If the url would help, here it is: http://sharedchecklist.com/

Thanks for any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Facebook where to redirect to. If it works in development you probably have your site url set to "http://localhost:3000". Change it to "http://sharedchecklist.com" and it will work. Of course it then will break in development. Therefore I created a new "Test" Facebook application just for my testing which always redirects to localhost.

Comment: Thanks for your answers Jason and Radu. I was able to fix the issue. It turned out that it was a problem with my server (it was displaying that the gem was installed but it actually wasn't?). The problem has been resolved in any case.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen if config/initializers/omniauth.rb is missing.

I have that file on the ignore list and a sample file as omniauth.rb.sample. I forgot to create the omniauth.rb file and I was getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test on local host and keep your production environment working:

1- Create a new Facebook app only for development purposes

2- Set the Site URL field to: `http://localhost:3000/`

3- Then edit your `/config/initializers/omniauth.rb` file to match the following:

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  if Rails.env.development?
    OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
    provider :facebook, 'DEV_APP_ID', 'DEV_APP_SEVRET'
  else
    provider :facebook, 'DEPLOY_APP_ID', 'DEPLOY_APP_SECRET'
  end
end
```

Finally relaunch `rails server` and you should be able to login through your new app.